# Run a sub process, provide Multiple input and output to it correctly in Java

Tags: java

I use Runtime exec() method to create a subprocess in Java. However, since the subprocess is an interactive program, I need to provide input to it as and when required by it. Also I need to show the output of the subprocess. How can I do this in the simplest possible way?

I was using a StreamGobbler to show the program output using process.getInputStream(). I, however, do not know how to identify when the program is waiting for input and when to provide it input using proc.getOutputStream. How can I do this?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

class StreamCopier implements Runnable {
private InputStream in;
private OutputStream out;

public StreamCopier(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    this.in = in;
    this.out = out;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        int n;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, n);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}

class InputCopier implements Runnable {
private FileChannel in;
private OutputStream out;

public InputCopier(FileChannel in, OutputStream out) {
    this.in = in;
    this.out = out;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        int n;
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
        while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer.array(), 0, n);
            out.flush();
        }
        out.close();
    }
    catch (AsynchronousCloseException e) {}
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}

public class Test {
private static FileChannel getChannel(InputStream in)throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
{
        Field f = FilterInputStream.class.getDeclaredField("in");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        while (in instanceof FilterInputStream)
            in = (InputStream)f.get((FilterInputStream)in);
        return ((FileInputStream)in).getChannel();
}

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, InterruptedException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
{

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Sum");
    Thread outThread = new Thread(new StreamCopier(process.getInputStream(), System.out));
    outThread.start();

    Thread errThread = new Thread(new StreamCopier(process.getErrorStream(), System.err));
    errThread.start();

    Thread inThread = new Thread(new InputCopier(getChannel(System.in), process.getOutputStream()));
    inThread.start();

    process.waitFor();
    System.in.close();
    outThread.join();
    errThread.join();
    inThread.join();
}
}
```

The above code is for executing a Sum.java file.

```
import java.io.*;
class Sum
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.print("\nEnter second number: ");
    int b = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    int c=a+b;
    System.out.println("\nThe sum of two number is: "+c);
}
}
```

[Output image after normal compiling and by using Test class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8XFc.png)

After using Test class program the output is different. How to solve this problem?

Advance Thank you!!!!!

Comment: I would try to  debug step-by-step Test.java and look where it stops/wait or missread something.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your error is in the reading algorithm of InputCopier:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer.array(), 0, n);
```

In the `while` instruction, `read(buffer)` reads contents and stores them (implicitly) at the current writing position of ByteBuffer (at the end). But aftter that, you are writing to the `out` *the whole* backing buffer when you invoke `buffer.array()`.

Nevertheless, I suggest you to drop `StreamCopier` and use always `InputCopier` to copy every stream on another.

And also to set the threads as daemon, not to block the JVM when the execution ends.

Comment: The solution provided by you would help me in my final year diploma project. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm very glad to help you... but a little upvote won't hurt me, either... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I got your code running with a plain InputStream:

```
class InputCopier implements Runnable {

    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;

    public InputCopier(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
    }

public void run() {
    try {
        int n;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[4096];
        while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, n);
            out.flush();
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (AsynchronousCloseException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The solution provided by you would help me in my final year diploma project. Thank you so much.